# Firefox select text range

Tags: javascript, firefox, selection

A quick question: how do I programatically select the text fragment of the page in FireFox? For example, there's a paragraph of text, user clicks the button and symbols from 10-th to 15-th are selected as if user dragged a mouse in a regular way.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by “symbols from 10-th to 15-th”? Characters in a paragraph element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Firefox, you can use the [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range) object, as specified by [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">   
    <title>Range test</title>
    <style>   
        #trigger { background: lightgreen }
    </style>                 
  </head>                    
  <body>                     
    <p id="test">This is some (rather short) text.</p>
    <span id="trigger">→ Click here! ←</span>
      <!-- Yes, I know, ‘Click here!’ is an evil message -->
    <script>
var testCase = function () {
    var userSelection;

    if (window.getSelection) {  // W3C default
        userSelection = window.getSelection();
    }  // an extra branch would be necessary if you want to support IE

    var textNode = document.getElementById('test').firstChild;
    var theRange = document.createRange();

    // select 10th–15th character (counting starts at 0)
    theRange.setStart(textNode, 9);
    theRange.setEnd(textNode, 14);

    // set user selection    
    userSelection.addRange(theRange);
};

window.onload = function () {
    var el = document.getElementById('trigger');
    el.onclick = testCase;
};
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that you have to get the `TextNode` to set the selection, which is the `firstChild` of the `<p>` element. Also note that this example **will not work** in IE, you have to use some proprietary methods. A nice introduction is on [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a way to do it for arbitrary DOM elements like paragraphs, but for textarea elements, I believe you need to use the [`selectionStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Property/selectionStart) and [`selectionEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL%3aProperty%3aselectionEnd) properties and specify where to start and end.

```
var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
textarea.selectionStart = 10;
textarea.selectionEnd = 15;
```

Hope this helps!